# Deriving Lagrange's Auxiliary equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, solution-verification, vector-fields, parametrization

**Setup:**

Let $z = U(x,y)$

Let $p = \frac{\partial U}{\partial x}$, $q = \frac{\partial U}{\partial y}$

Lagrange's Linear Equation:

$$Pp + Qq = R \tag{1} $$where $P,Q,R$ are polynomials of $x,y,z$

**To be proved:**

Lagrange's Auxiliary Equations:
$$ \frac{dx}{P} = \frac{dy}{Q} =\frac{dz}{R} $$

**Method (yields wrong result):**

Rewriting equation 1:
$$ Pp + Qq - R = 0 \tag{2}$$
Consider vectors $\bar{v}$ and $\bar{u}$

$$\bar{u} = ( p, q, 1 ) \tag{3}$$

$$\bar{v} = ( P, Q, -R ) \tag{4}$$

By equations 2,3,4:

$$(p,q,r).(P,Q,-R)=0 \tag{5}$$

Because $\bar{u}$ = $\nabla u$ :
Equation 5:
$$\nabla u.\bar{v} = 0 \tag{6}$$

Therefore general solution from 6:
Any vector along $\bar{v}$

Therefore by parametric form:
$$ \frac{dx}{P} = \frac{dy}{Q} =\frac{dz}{-R} $$

But this is not the same as Lagrange's auxiliary equations. :(

Comment: You might find the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_characteristics) interesting.

Comment: Thanks! The way I took the normal vector was incorrect :)